# C# DateTime Parse/convert this format "20120314T130000"

Tags: c#, .net

I am using an API that outputs dates in this format 20120314T130000 .

The date value is 13:00 14 March 2012. How can I parse a Date in this format to a .Net DateTime variable in C#?

Also what is this date format known as?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's ISO 8601. The '-' separators are optional in this format.

You can't parse it with the normal DateTime.Parse method, but you can use [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

If you have a mix of dates, some with separators and some without, you might need to use a regex to extract the relevant information and then construct the DateTime object.